# How to modify the protocol of matcher in faster-RCNN

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am currently using Faster-RCNN from the Tensorflow object detection API to train on my own data.

I would like to change the positive IoU value and negative IoU value of "**argmax_matcher**". What fields should I modify in the .config file?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, argmax_matcher is not a valid configuration for Faster R-CNN, but only of SSD.
Instead, you can change the values that are given to the function call in function `create_target_assigner()` of /core/target_assigner.py. 
You can change both the first stage:

`reference == 'FasterRCNN' and stage == 'proposal'`

and the second:

`reference == 'FasterRCNN' and stage == 'detection'`.

The relevant parameters are of course `matched_threshold` and `unmatched_threshold`. You should probably set `force_match_for_each_row` to `True`, and note `negatives_lower_than_unmatched` is `True` by default.